# Supposed to be Chi Squared

Tags: probability

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N(0,1)$. Define $Y = X_1^2 + X_2^2$ and $Z = X_2$.

We want to find the joint pdf of $Y$ and $Z$.

My attempt:

$P(Y=y,Z=z) \\= P(X_1^2 + X_2^2 = y, X_2 = z) \\ 
= P(X_1^2 + X_2^2 = y | X_2 = z)P(X_2 = z) \\
= P(X_1^2 = y - z^2)P(X_2 = z) \\
= \left[P(X_1 = -\sqrt{y-z^2}) + P(X_1 = \sqrt{y-z^2})\right]P(X_2 = z) \\
= \frac{1}{\pi}e^{-\frac{y}{2}}$

But when I try to get the marginal for $f_Y(y)$, I don't get the chi squared distribution, so I believe there's something wrong with my calculations.

Comment: Asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873023/change-of-variables-technique-to-show-that-for-iid-standard-normals-x-1-x-2/) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2869097/finding-the-probability-distribution-using-transformations?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write $\mathbb{P}[Y=y,Z=z]$, since this will be $0$. But still you can write exactly what you did with the pdf but then conclude using the fact that [$X_1^2$ is a $\chi_1^2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) :
\begin{align*}
f_{Y,Z}(y,z) &= f_{X_1^2}(y-z^2) f_{X_2}(z)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{y-z^2}} e^{-\frac{y-z^2+z^2}{2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{y-z^2}} e^{-\frac{y}{2}}
\end{align*}

The marginal distribution of $Y$ is indeed a $\chi_2^2$ since [the integral over $z$ of this converges to the right value](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20z%20from%20-sqrt(y)%20to%20sqrt(y)%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%5Csqrt%7By-z%5E2%7D%7D%20e%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B2%7D%7D)

The other marginal [also checks to be a gaussian](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((integral%20y%20from%20z%5E2%20to%20inf)%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%5Cpi%5Csqrt%7By-z%5E2%7D%7D%20e%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7By%7D%7B2%7D%7D)).

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. I'm curious to know why it's wrong to do $f_{X_1^2}(y-z^2) = f_{X_1}(\sqrt{y-z^2}) + f_{X_1}(-\sqrt{y-z^2})$ then evaluate that

Comment: well, there is actually a problem with my answer, the integral over $y$ doesn't seem to converge, I will try to figure it out.

regarding your answer, you would want to apply the formula for the PDF of a transformation, which involves multiplying by the Jacobian. In the end this is equivalent to using the CDF instead which is often a good idea.

Comment: Well actually it was correct.

Comment: Awesome. I'm trying to use the CDF to solve it now. Does this also involve multiplying by the Jacobian?

Comment: not really, at some point you will have $\mathbb{P}[X_1^2 \leq a] = \mathbb{P}[-\sqrt{a} \leq X_1 \leq \sqrt{a}]$, the Jacobian is in a sense "contained" in this equality, this is because this inequality contains the information of the transformation. Note that with this writing the equality is obvious but when we write it with PDF, we tend to believe that they are probabilities (which they are not). Actually your first statement is correct $\mathbb{P}(X^2 = a^2) = \mathbb{P}(X = a) + \mathbb{P}(X=-a)$, but those probabilities are $0$